# How to implement dynamic image slideshow

Tags: jquery, tabs

I'd like to know https://kippt.com/ implements the following javascript for a dynamic tabbed area:

http://jsfiddle.net/itzamacko/ykdCT/

I would like to know how this is done so I may emulate it for my own project, but I've been battling with getting it working locally for a day or so :/

Any insight into how this implementation works would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Developer of Kippt here. It seems that you forgot to switch to correct JS library: Kippt's codebase is build with jQuery, not Mootools. Here's the working version:

http://jsfiddle.net/itzamacko/ykdCT/

I also copypasted the correct CSS to CSS tab. If you have any questions about the implementation, I'm happy to answer them.